# image in email just printing url

Tags: php, html, image, email, variables

I have a simple php email script where I wish to include an image at the bottom. When I add the image tags like below the email just shows `<img src="http://domain.com/images/logo.png" />` instead of the actual image. Any ideas why?

```
<?PHP
$email = $_POST["emailaddress"];

$to = "you@youremail.com";
$subject = "New Email Address for Mailing List";
$headers = "From: $email\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$message = "A visitor to your site has sent the following email address to be added to your mailing list.\n

Email Address: $email";

$user = "$email";
$usersubject = "Thank You";
$userheaders = "From: info@domain.com\n";

$usermessage = 

"
Thank you for joining our mailing list.

We hope to see you very soon!

Address 1 
Address 2
<img src=\"http://domain.com/images/logo.png\" />
";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);

$fh = fopen("email.xml", "a");
fwrite($fh, "$email\r\n");
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Comment: i noticed you declared the actual HTML in $usermessage. have you tried (I'm not certain what the code is, been a long time since i touched php) something along the lines of
$usermessage = "Thank you ... " & <img src="http://domain.com/images/logo.png" />

Comment: Loads of errors in your code. First thing you need some <br/>'s in your message. Second if you want the image to show you need at least one more header: Content-Transfer-Encoding P.S. mail() is the worst possible way to send an email. Try SMTP.

Comment: @tntu I tried your suggesttion with adding $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"; but it doesn't work. Is 8bit the wrong one to use?

Comment: Try to add the following header: `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the Content-Type header with the right message. `$headers` does contain the right header, but it is sent with a plain text message, whereas `$userheaders` does not contain the `Content-Type` header, but the message associated with it does contain some HTML

Replace

```
$userheaders = "From: info@domain.com\n";
```

with

```
$userheaders = "From: info@domain.com\r\n";
$userheaders = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
```

and it should work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This is a word press plugin but if you delete everything BUT the XmailBaby class it should work for you nicely.
That code is a nice piece of work that sends emails very good.
It is just a basic version but it should be enough for you.
Take a look through the code, you might find it interesting.

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/xmail-the-right-way/trunk/xmail.php

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify html headers. Rather than do this yourself, you can use a well-established method that supports sending HTML emails, such as PHPMailer:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: post some evidence to backup your claims or don't bother posting, thx

Comment: Setting aside that it does not respect the RFC regulations very well, but hey nobody does respect them to to letter. It has some difficulties delivering emails because for it's complexity it should at least make sure the content is properly formatted to at least pass via the content filters like spam assassin. There are loads of reports about it not delivering to Hotmail and other providers. If there was one report you might say that he has a blacklisted IP but there are many. I have encountered it a lot of times and kicked it out and just delivered manually via SMTP with some content fixing.

Comment: "Jim Jagielski is taking over the project. Jim has an outstanding background including being a founding member of the Apache Foundation and former CTO of Zend Technologies." --- seems not legit.

Comment: Then I hope the future brings better results then the present. All I know at the moment it's not good enough.